# samba: unable to delete directories

Tags: 14.04, samba

From my samba share on ubuntu, I am unable to delete directories. Deleting files is just fine. I can log in as the samba user over ssh and delete the same dir.
Every directory is set to `drwxrwxrwx` as well as mount point and every file is `-rwxrwxrwx`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following in the share definition of your ´smb.conf´:

```
directory mask = 0777
```

This parameter is used in the calculation of permission from Windows to Linux From the [documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html): "The default value of this parameter removes the 'group' and 'other' write bits from the UNIX mode, allowing only the user who owns the directory to modify it."